# MIT Licesne - include in iOS App

Tags: ios, mobile-application

My boss wants me to create an app for inside usage of the company( a prototype), and I need to use a MIT licensed software.

When I look at the license it says:
"The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.".
Am I obligated to put credits in the app? he didn't ask for that and creating for a menu with credits button will take time for me that will cost him money. Am I allowed to keep the license in the source Code and not display it, even though the source code is compiled and not disclosed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about UX.

Comment: This sounds like a legal question to me - Have you tried over at https://law.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An MIT licence is free to use.
You are not obligated at all to add credits in your app when you use it.

This is what you need to do:

- When you release source code, put a copy of the MIT License text at
  the top of each source file as a comment.
- When you release a software package, include a copy of the MIT License in the root directory of the package. Name the file ‘COPYING’ or ‘LICENSE’.
- Display the MIT License as part of your software's End User License Agreement (EULA).
- Display the MIT License in any documentation.